# Weird Image with SVG in src attribute in Edge browser

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I'm rendering image and I'm passing svg file as source  attribute to image. It works perfect on all  browsers, except Edge. I  cant find  an reason why it  renders this weird black box  with cross:

[image]

Html code of is like:  `<img width="3029"  height="3920" id="id_of_image" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns=....................CONTENT OF SVG............></svg>"/>`

How can I show this kind  of  image also  on edge?  I'm  filling src  attribute  from  JS where I  have   element  as  string. I need to put it into image  attribute,  but  question is how is that possible?

Comment: I made a test with the code like yours: https://jsfiddle.net/yuzhou0602/wph8rguc/2/, and it works well in Edge. You could run my test demo in Edge. My Edge version is 44.18362.1.0. Is there something wrong in your svg code? What's the version of Edge you're using? You could use F12 dev tools to check if there's any error or warning in console. Also please provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can test it in our sides and to see how to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Issue was that in Edge it had problem with rendering svg when you are using tags directly in attributes. So solution was to replace and  convert string in JS. I created function to generate SVG attribute for  image from ajax request, when you have your SVG string:

```
function fixSVGDiagram(svgString)  {
    svgString = svgString.replace("<![CDATA[", "").replace("]]>", ""); //If styles occured, Edge crashes on that

    svgString = svgString.replace(/#/g,"temporaryhash") //Because of hasthag issues (in styles)

    svgString = encodeURI(svgString) //Magic  happens

    svgString = svgString.replace(/temporaryhash/g, "%23") //Get back  hashtag

    return "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + svgString
}
```

If  you are loading SVG  as attribute in ajax  request then you can store it as  string:

```
svgData = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(responseData);
```

and then

```
var  img = new Image
img.src = fixSVGDiagram(svgData)
```

and you  can put image where you want.

Answer (score 0):

svg code doesn't work like this for svg image.
Without the use of image tag you can directly use the svg tag in the html code.
OR.

You can create an svg file with *.svg extension and set the filename as the src in the image attribute.

Comment: this is exactly what I cant (because of rest code in app), it works great in all brorwsers, but there  it doesnt  in Edge browser

Comment: When I use that string  as SVG file, then it renders correctly

Comment: So you can use that

Comment: I cannot use just svg file, because I'm loading svg string through ajax :)